# Can't import matplotlib (anaconda)

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have installed anaconda 4.4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have had some trouble with importing matplotlib.pyplot. I have looked through a bunch of sites, but no answers would fix my problem.

Here's the error message that I get:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 26, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 128, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

## Edit

The error message changed:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 25, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 15, in <module>
    from six.moves import zip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'; 'six' is not a package
```

Comment: "'six' is not a package"- do you have six package installed? If not, then install it.

Comment: I do have it installed as i can run `import six as six` without any errors

Comment: Check if you have six in `/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages` or in `/home/lucasgruwez/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib` if not, then it is maybe installed, but for wrong python in linux you have usually few versions of python.

Comment: Quick edit, `import six as six` does give me an error (didn't earlier today though...) It gives the same error but starting from the line with `/six.py` six.py is installed in the site-packages directory...

Comment: I see your errors are still changing? What do you do, so they change?

Comment: Try first run it as root (sudo) to check if this isn't permissions issue.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and reinstall some packages and that's probably why the errors keep changing. I'm now abandoning anaconda and I'm trying to install matplotlib with apt-get

Comment: I didn't get any errors with the apt-get version

Comment: I'm not sure if apt-get will install it for python 3.6. Use python shell for 3.6, import pip, then `pip.main(['install', 'matplotlib'])`

Comment: I do get an error, it says "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"

Comment: For me it is separate question. I sugest, you to answer yourself at first question and post a new one.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it and was able to get a graph output!!!